# c# simple login form

Tags: c#, authentication, computer-science

I'm trying to make just a little login form. I'm getting error called } expected.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        String username = "motify";
        String password = "0w0";

        if ((textBox1.Text == username) && (textBox2.Text == password))
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, Guest!", "NetChecker 0.5");
        this.Hide();
        Form1 frm2 = new Form1();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
            else
        MessageBox.Show("Hit the 'How to login?' button to get login details!", "NetChecker 0.5");
    }
}
```

}

full login.cs: https://pastebin.com/LXkBt9eC

Comment: You have an _else_ without a matching _if_

Comment: Youre not using the brackets for the if else statement. You can only ignore them if you use ONLY ONE line of code below the if/else. In your case you have more than one line and therefore youre getting this error. I hope I helped you. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try using this. Use proper indention while coding.
Thanks.

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String username = "motify";
    String password = "0w0";

    if ((textBox1.Text == username) && (textBox2.Text == password))
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, Guest!", "NetChecker 0.5");
        this.Hide();
        Form1 frm2 = new Form1();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    }
    else
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Hit the 'How to login?' button to get login details!", "NetChecker 0.5");
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I am Newbie on Stack Overflow, don't know about this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You haven't opened the brackets for the if statement:

```
  if ((textBox1.Text == username) && (textBox2.Text == password))
{ //This bracket
            MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, Guest!", "NetChecker 0.5");
        this.Hide();
        Form1 frm2 = new Form1();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
}// And this bracket
            else
    MessageBox.Show("Hit the 'How to login?' button to get login details!", "NetChecker 0.5");
```

An if statement performs the line of code after it, if you use brackets {} you can wrap multiple lines to be performed by the if statement, then you can use the else statement after those brackets.

Answer (score 0):

In Your this code

```
private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String username = "motify";
    String password = "0w0";

    if ((textBox1.Text == username) && (textBox2.Text == password))
        MessageBox.Show("Welcome back, Guest!", "NetChecker 0.5");
        this.Hide();
        Form1 frm2 = new Form1();
        frm2.ShowDialog();
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Hit the 'How to login?' button to get login details!","NetChecker 0.5");
}
```

please write if using '{}' braces , because if you have only one statement inside if then only you can write without curly bracese.

Comment: Why did you post an exact copy of an existing answer?

Comment: it not a copy , I have specify that why it is not working.